# Can I use python versions 3.8.5 vs 3.8.8 interchangeably?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am troubleshooting a problem in which some code doesn't work on a new computer with a fresh install of python/anaconda. One suggestion that has been made to me is to ensure that the code is running on the same version of python. The older computer that successfully runs the code runs Python 3.8.5, while the newer that can't run the code runs 3.8.8.

Is this a big enough difference to potentially cause problems?

I have learned that Anaconda allows to change between different python versions. But, as shown in the [tutorial](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/use-multiple-python-versions/#:%7E:text=In%20Navigator%2C%20click%20the%20Environments,version%20you%20want%20to%20use.), there are a limited number of versions that are allowed:

[image]

Here I can use 3.8.13, but do not have access to 3.8.5 or 3.8.8. Is this because all three versions are essentially compatible, and there's not a significant enough difference to want 3.8.5 vs 3.8.8?

Comment: conda provides pretty much every min/patch version going back to 3.5.4 at least (and 2.7.x) . That seems to be a tutorial for the anaconda navigator. I'm not super familiar with that, but it is pretty trivial to create a new conda environment with python 3.8.5

Comment: that being said, I highly, highly doubt that this is the cause of your issue. it's *possible* but improbable, so this to me seems like a classic [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the issue you are *actually trying to solve*?

Comment: And note, theoretically, with semantic versioning, `3.X.Y` should work for any `X.Y` in a backwards compatible way, only major version changes should be backwards incompatible

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592, and try to show *actual code* that runs under 3.8.5 but not 3.8.8; show *how* it fails to run on 3.8.8; and try to identify any *other* differences between the two environments besides the actual Python version. Please keep in mind that this is *not a discussion forum*; we do not deal in speculation.

Comment: @Karl knechtel, I am a long time poster with many well recieved questions. I know the rules well enough to know that I am asking a reasonable question, and I do not and cannot provide example code.

Comment: "...cannot provide example code." I cannot fathom a legitimate reason for this. At the *very least*, why not explain what "can't run the code" entails? What happens when you try? Is there an error message? Then [show a complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, you can't fathom it? The python code talks to an AWG (arbitrary waveform geneator), and involves a lot of physical dependencies. You wouldn't be able to run my code without it breaking for completely different reasons because you don't have the hardware to run it.  I have already recieved a satisfactory answer to the question.

Comment: Generally speaking, if I were to try running Python 3 code using python 2, I think most people here would agree this is unwise and that any errors I am seeing might be due to a discrepancy in the version differences -- and that before troubleshooting, I should just run the right version. Now is that also likely to be the case for 3.8.8 vs 3.8.5? The answer that I have gotten from the community is that I would have to get somewhat unlucky for this to be the reason as there are very few cases where this would be the case.

Comment: If the question is "how likely is it that this is a Python version problem?", then that is not a question appropriate for Stack Overflow, since it calls for speculation. If the question is "how do I determine whether the Python version is to blame?", then you do that by the steps I have already outlined for you, which again are things people are expected to do before asking on Stack Overflow. I did not give you links in order to spite you; I gave you links because they explain the problem with a question like this.

Comment: That is complete nonsense. To quote the answerer "Minor versions usually mean no major functionality was changed/removed, but you might still get slightly different results for various functions", there is nothing "speculative" about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the changes on the official [changelog page](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/changelog.html).

Minor versions usually mean no major functionality was changed/removed, but you might still get slightly different results for various functions

Comment: This is technically a patch version change, not a minor version change

Comment: Ok, so I would have to get pretty unlucky for my code to break if it were 3.8.5.

Comment: "A lot of toxicity and down votes for what I believe to be a completely reasonable question" There is no toxicity here. We are trying to explain, as politely as possible, why the question is not actually as reasonable as you believe.